# What is changed in fonts configuration from 10.10 to 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, firefox, fonts

I'm not able to obtain sharp (acceptable) fonts, specially in Firefox, in Natty.

In Maverick I've to delete `/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-` files and set 'hinting full' in gnome-appearance-properties. This solution doesn't works in Natty.

I've tried many combinations linking *.conf files from `/etc/fonts/conf.avail` to `/etc/fonts/conf.d`, I've tried to use a custom conf file (`.fonts.conf`), I've tried modifying dpi, I've tried with various ttf (including Microsoft fonts), but no way. The result is always unacceptable.

So my question is, how can I have the same behaviors of Maverick fonts in Natty?

**Edit**

This seems a problem with (at least) Arial font. If i force Firefox to use a different font (eg Sans) 
it's all right, but obviously this is not a solution (i don't want all sites have the same 
font). Below an animated gif that show the differences of Ariel font:

[image]

Take a look at "1,a,G" chars (right click on the image and select to view in other tab)

Answer (score 1):

1. set this (/etc/fonts/conf.d/):

   10-antialias.conf -> ../conf.avail/10-antialias.conf

   10-hinting.conf -> ../conf.avail/10-hinting.conf

   **10-hinting-medium.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-hinting-medium.conf****
2. run and close firefox
3. change setting to full hinting:

   10-antialias.conf -> ../conf.avail/10-antialias.conf

   10-hinting.conf -> ../conf.avail/10-hinting.conf

   **10-hinting-full.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-hinting-full.conf****
4. run firefox

Comment: Or try to run 'dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig'.

Comment: thank you for the hit, but in my system "medium" and "full" hinting doesn't show any differences.